# Can CTPH ( Context-Triggered Piece wise Hash : Fuzzy hash ) occur collision?

Tags: algorithm, hash

As same as title.

i'm researching for `hash` functions to extract signature from windows excutable file.

i found `Fuzzy hash` and `CTPH`, but i don't know these hash algorithms are safe or not.

i want to know the `CTPH` occur collision or not.

example:

```
a : f(a)
b : f(b)

f(a) != f(b)
```

this is necessary

```
f(a) == f(b)
```

I don't want this situation.

if `CTPH` can occur this situation, then please let me know the probability of collision.

Thanks.

Comment: Almost all hash algorithms can produce collisions due to the pigeon hole principle.

Comment: First, thanks for your reply.
i also know about pigeon hole principle. but i want to know its probability. thanks.

Comment: Of which hashing algorithm?

Comment: Context-Triggered Piece wise Hash.

Basically, Fuzzy Hashing algorithm.

Comment: CTPH and fuzzy hashing are techniques used to obtain hash values where individual parts of the hash depends on individual parts of the input. They use traditional hashing algorithms however and you have to choose which ones to use. I am, however, going out on a limb here stating that knowledge about collision probability here is not actually known as no paper I've read on these techniques handle that part of the problem. Here's one such paper: [Identifying almost identical files using context triggered
piecewise hashing - Jesse Kornblum](http://dfrws.org/2006/proceedings/12-Kornblum.pdf).

Comment: Since two files that are mostly indentical produces hash values that are mostly identical I would find it quite reasonable that the chance of collision is much higher than for a traditional hash algorithm.

Comment: In fact, since the goal of fuzzy hashing and CTPH is to get as closely matching hash values for closely matching files as possible, I would guess that obtaining unique hash values for unique files is probably not an important consideration.